# related to the xmppframework and openfire server in ios

Tags: ios

I am implementing XMPP framework and trying to connect the openfire server in swift, but I don't understand following line.

```
"stream.myJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString("xxxxxx")"
```

So, which jid will provide in stream.myjid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First you will add xmppRoster or xmppRoom in xmppStream by activating it. And then you will try to connect by giving your JID and password to authorize. Your JID can be anything that can be uniquely defined like userName@ServerUrl. Like this:

```
let jabberID = "\(username)@\(Constants.Url.chatBaseUrl)"
            self.password = "12345"

            if !xmppStream.isDisconnected() {
                return true
            }
            if jabberID == "" && self.password == "" {
                return false
            }

            xmppStream.myJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString(jabberID)

            do {
                try xmppStream.connectWithTimeout(XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
                print("Connection success")
                return true
            } catch {
                print("Something went wrong!")
                return false
            }
```

Comment: i am done with this but i little bit confuse to jid myjid is server Property admin jid or username which creted on server. elabrate it thanks

Comment: This JID is your unique identifier by which all the messages send to this JID will be routed to your stream. So it will be username or whatever you want to give doesnt matter but in the end whatever combination you are making for JID it should be unique as it will act as a address you can say or nodes.